# Defer the selection of a child validator depending on the property type/value

Tags: .net, validation, expression-trees, fluentvalidation, simple-injector

In FluentValidation is there an extension or some other way to defer the selection of a child validator depending on the type/value of the property being validated?

My situation is that I have a Notification class that I want to validate. This class has a Payload property, which can be one of a number of Payload types e.g. SmsPayload, EmailPayload etc. Each of these Payload subclasses has their own associated validator e.g. SmsPayloadValidator and EmailPayloadValidator respectively. In addition to the above, there is no references from the core library(ies) to the individual notification providers. Essentially, this means I can add providers on an as needed basis and wire everything up using IoC.

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Notification
{
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Details { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Payload
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}

public class SmsPayload : Payload
{
    public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
}
```

There is a Notification validator and SmsPayloadValidator as follows:

```
public class NotificationValidator : AbstractValidator<Notification>
{
    public NotificationValidator(IValidator<Payload> payloadValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(notification => notification.Payload).NotNull().WithMessage("Payload cannot be null.");
        RuleFor(notification => notification.Payload).SetValidator(payloadValidator);
    }
}

public class SmsPayloadValidator : AbstractValidator<SmsPayload>
{
    public SmsPayloadValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(payload => payload.Provider)
            .Must(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .WithMessage("Provider is required.");
        RuleFor(payload => payload.Numbers)
            .Must(list => list != null && list.Any())
            .WithMessage("Sms has no phone numbers specified.");
        RuleFor(payload => payload.Region)
            .Must(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .WithMessage("Region is required.");
    }
}
```

As I mentioned the assembly where the NotificationValidator is does not reference the assemblies where the individual Payload validator classes live. All the wiring is taken care of by Ioc (Simple-Injector for this project).

Basically I want to do something like the following - first by registering a factory callback in Simple Injector:

```
container.Register<Func<Payload, IValidator<Payload>>>(() => (payload =>
{
    if (payload.GetType() == typeof(SmsPayload))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<ISmsPayloadValidator>();
    }
    else if (payload.GetType() == typeof(EmailPayload))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<IEmailPayloadValidator>();
    }
    else 
    {
        //something else;
    }
}));
```

Such that I can select the appropriate validator as follows:

```
public class NotificationValidator : AbstractValidator<Notification>
{
    public NotificationValidator(Func<Payload, IValidator<Payload>> factory)
    {
        RuleFor(notification => notification.Payload).NotNull().WithMessage("Payload cannot be null.");
        RuleFor(notification => notification.Payload).SetValidator(payload => factory.Invoke(payload));
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? or is there a better way to do what I'm proposing?
If none, I'll fork the FluentValidation repository and submit a PR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might make your intentions a little more clear by avoiding the factory. While the end result is probably the same with this approach, you can at least end up injecting `IValidator<Payload>` directly instead of `Func<Payload, IValidator<Payload>>`.

Create a class called `PolymorphicValidator`. This will allow you to repeat this pattern in a consistent manner, as well as provide a fallback base validator if you so desire. This is essentially the recommended "composite pattern" described [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#collections) in the Simple Injector documentation.

```
public class PolymorphicValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IValidator<T> _baseValidator;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IValidator> _validatorMap = new Dictionary<Type,IValidator>();

    public PolymorphicValidator() { }

    public PolymorphicValidator(IValidator<T> baseValidator)
    {
        _baseValidator = baseValidator;
    }

    public PolymorphicValidator<T> RegisterDerived<TDerived>(IValidator<TDerived> validator) where TDerived : T
    {
        _validatorMap.Add(typeof (TDerived), validator);
        return this;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context)
    {
        var instance = context.InstanceToValidate;
        var actualType = instance == null ? typeof(T) : instance.GetType();
        IValidator validator;
        if (_validatorMap.TryGetValue(actualType, out validator))
            return validator.Validate(context);
        if (_baseValidator != null)
            return _baseValidator.Validate(context);
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Attempted to validate unsupported type '{0}'. " +
            "Provide a base class validator if you wish to catch additional types implicitly.", actualType));
    }
}
```

You can then register your validator like this (optionally providing a base class fallback and additional child class validators):

```
container.RegisterSingle<SmsPayloadValidator>();
//container.RegisterSingle<EmailPayloadValidator>();
container.RegisterSingle<IValidator<Payload>>(() =>
    new PolymorphicValidator<Payload>(/*container.GetInstance<PayloadValidator>()*/)
        .RegisterDerived(container.GetInstance<SmsPayloadValidator>())
      /*.RegisterDerived(container.GetInstance<EmailPayloadValidator>() */);
```

This will create a singleton `PolymorphicValidator` which contains singleton child validators (Singletons are recommended by the FluentValidation team). You can now inject `IValidator<Payload>` as shown in your first `NotificationValidator` example.

```
public class NotificationValidator : AbstractValidator<Notification>
{
    public NotificationValidator(IValidator<Payload> payloadValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(notification => notification.Payload)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Payload cannot be null.")
            .SetValidator(payloadValidator);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the composite. I however think that your implementation is a more complex than needed. See my answer for an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. However, I would argue that my approach is no more "complex" than yours. More tedious, yes. Perhaps impractical as you mention in your answer, but only depending on the implementor's intentions.

Comment: While slightly more complicated, it's a little more explicit and I it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Taylor's answer about using a Composite (so definitely +1 for that), but his implementation not that practical. I therefore suggest a slightly different implementation, while still using the composite.

If I'm not mistaken, your composite should look as follows:

```cs
public class CompositeValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public CompositeValidator(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(T instance)
    {
        var validators = this.container.GetAllInstances(instance.GetType());

        return new ValidationResult(
            from IValidator validator in validators
            from error in validator.Validate(instance).Errors
            select error);
    }
}
```

The registration should be as follows:

```cs
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IValidator<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), 
    typeof(CompositeValidator<>), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton);

// Simple Injector v2.x
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IValidator<>),
    container.RegisterAll,
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IValidator<>), 
    typeof(CompositeValidator<>), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

What happens here is the following:

- The `RegisterCollection` call ensures that all validators are registered as collections. This means that for each T, there can be multiple validators in it. For instance, if your system has a `PayloadValidator` and a `SmsPayloadValidator`, resolving `GetAllInstances<IValidator<SmsPayload>>` will return both validators, because `IValidator<in T>` contains the `in` keyword (is contravariant).
- The `Register` registration will register the `CompositeValidator<T>` to be returned for each `IValidator<T>` that is requested. Since Simple Injector [differentiates registrations of collections with one-to-one registrations](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections), injecting an `IValidator<T>` will always result in the composite validator to be injected. Since the composite validator only depends on the container, it can be registered as singleton.
- Consumers get injected with the `CompositeValidator<T>` (when they depend on `IValidator<T>`) and the composite validator will ask for a collection of validators based on the exact type. So in case a consumer uses a `IValidator<Payload>`, the composite validator will determine the real type (`SmsPayload` for instance) and request all assignable validators for this exact type and will forward the validations to these types.
- If there are no validators for a specific type, the composite validator will automatically return a valid `ValidationResult`.

Comment: +1 For a more generic solution. You may have a slight advantage as you are a developer of the framework, and I just learned about it as I read this question... lol. One thing for onlookers to note is while this solution is less verbose to implement, it is also less flexible than my solution. It is inferred that the implementor always wants to register and use all validators for a specific type. If that is your intention, then this is definitely the superior approach.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan: It's very noteworthy that you did some analysis as reading the docs, just to answer this question. Not many people do that here on Stackoverflow.